# CoreData + restkit + creating new entities

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit-0.20

I am using **RestKit** with **Coredata** and fetching data from the server and displaying.

Now I am doing a post from the client and this object gets updated as part of the response that comes back from the server. This is where the problems starts.

I looked for the correct way to implement this and came across 2 main points.

1. MOCs should not be shared across threads
2. An object created in the MOC is not available in another thread without saving.

But i think since the record gets updated from server response,  its no longer finding the orig object. I just dont knw what the right fix is.

Here is my code 
1. Create local entity

```
    NSEntityDescription *itemEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:ENTITY_ITEM inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    Item *item = [[Item alloc]initWithEntity:itemEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

// Set params on item here 

// Then save it 
    NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    DBGLog(@"Tried to save the new item but failed - error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}

// Then I make the RestKit call to post the item
// The server updates the item Id
[SharedManager postItem:item success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    // successful case         
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // failure case         
}];
```

It looks like when its trying to make the response it doesnt find the object.

And i get this exception -

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x156c87b0 <x-coredata://A42ABF18-01B6-4D78-B81B-62D8B604EB52/Item/p6>''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f853f0b 0x39feace7 0x2f5b7fd1 0x2f61a655 0x2f6246a7 0x2f6326e5 0x2f632a95 0x2f63356f 0x3a4d3d3f 0x3a4d86c3 0x2f628e7b 0x2f633271 0x2f5c7f49 0x1c67fb 0x2f62b9cd 0x3a4d9b3b 0x3a4d3d3f 0x3a4d66c3 0x2f81e681 0x2f81cf4d 0x2f787769 0x2f78754b 0x346f46d3 0x320e6891 0x72561 0x3a4e8ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type _NSCoreDataException
```

If I dont do a "save" then I see `Cocoa Error 133000` on 4S devices.  So there is definitely something I am messing up.

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: I realized that i my context was mainQueueManagedObjectContext when i believe it shoudl be persistentStoreManagedObjectContext. This might be the reason for it. Will update soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment is along the correct lines, but not the correct solution. The problem is that you only save the main thread context and the change doesn't get pushed up to the parent (the persistent context). So, instead of calling `if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {` you should be calling `if (![self.managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error]) {`

Comment: Thanks Wain. I see.. Should i continue to use the mainQueueManagedObjectContext? Isnt the persistentMOC the right one to use given that my restkit operations update the database? Also with persistentMOC all my save should be on performBlockAndWait?

Comment: You are creating a RestKit operation on the main thread and executing it so you should use the main context.

Comment: So if i understand what you are saying correctly, restkit operations are runing on the background thread but the operation was ccreated on the main thread and hence is ok using the main thread's context because response will be processed in the main thread?

Comment: Rereading, my comment is misleading. You aren't creating the operation yourself. You shouldn't ever interact with the persistent store context directly, always use a child appropriate to the thread you're on. Then, save up to the persistent store. It isn't about the response, it's about the source object you create being available in the persistent store. Using the persistent context would work but it's not something you want to do.

Comment: I understand but I guess my confusion is that the mainQueueMOC is only for main thread but since I am adding objects to the DB in the main thread and expecting RestKit to use that data to do a post which is happening on a background thread, what is the best way to do this? Is it enough to jsut saveToPersistentStore before making the RestKit call?

Comment: Yes, just `saveToPersistentStore`